# Schematron applied to different xsi namespaces

Tags: xml, xslt, xml-namespaces, schematron

We have a schematron with the xsi namespace declared as follows

```
   <schema xmlns="http://purl.oclc.org/dsdl/schematron" queryBinding='xslt2'>
   <ns prefix="xsi" uri="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
```

We do this because we want to define context-based rules as follows:

```
    <rule context="*[@xsi:type='DATA_TYPE']">...</rule>
```

These rules worked fine for the past XML files we received so far. However, we recently received a XML whose xsi namespace is defined as:

```
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2000/10/XMLSchema-instance"
```

This 'new' xsi namespace causes the rules defined above to not be fired (as rules do not share the same xsi). Is there a way to define schematron namespaces in a way that the rules would be fired independently of the xsi namespace?

There is always the option of defining the rules based on the local-name()="type" instead of using the xsi:type, but I was wondering if there is a correct (and better) way of achieving this.

Comment: (slightly ot): The [XSI namespace is reserved](http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance). This "new" xsi namespace is not an XSI namespace at all, from  a validation perspective, it _is just another namespace_. Also, you should **not need to check this validity with your schema**, quote: _"This reinforces the special status of these attributes, so that they not only need not be declared to be allowed in instances, but must not be declared. It also removes any temptation to experiment [..] for e.g. xsi:type or xsi:nil, which would be seriously misleading, as they would have no effect."_

Comment: Probably not that offtopic, as it gives a solution to the problem :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a version of the `XMLSchema-instance` namespace from an older spec.

You can add another prefix declaration for it:

```
<ns prefix="xsi_old" uri="http://www.w3.org/2000/10/XMLSchema-instance"/>
```

And then adjust your rules to test for both:

```
<rule context="*[@xsi:type='DATA_TYPE' or @xsi_old:type='DATA_TYPE']">...</rule>
```

Comment: But to do this you need to know the all namespaces existing in the world in advance. I assume there could be even older versions floating around.

Comment: Then disregard the namespace completely as you mentioned using `local-name()`, or, less broadly, test `namespace-uri()` to see if it contains `XMLSchema-instance`.

Comment: Another approach would be to have the document owner update their XML (or have a stage ahead of your normal Schematron processing that updates it automatically).   It has been 15 years since the "new" namespace was adopted, afterall.

Comment: Agree with you, probably the best think is to inform the owner, or just update the xsi namespace to the correct one when receiving it. I'll mark your answer as valid as you provided several ways to work around this, but fixing the source probably is the better option.